# eclipse doesn't run after installing another jdk version

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I had eclipse and jdk 1.8 installed on my computer for a few months since the day I started learning java, I had no problems until this week when I installed jdk 1.7 for software that does not support java 8 so eclipse start displaying an error : could not create the java virtual machine and eclipse won't run, I don't know if that was because of what I installed this week, please help me fix this issue whatever you know about this would help

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM